# c++ eigen static assert confuses enum with float

Tags: c++, enums, eigen

Here is the code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
enum { TWO = 2};
Matrix<float, Dynamic, TWO> m1(42, 2); // good...
Matrix<float, Dynamic, TWO> m2(42, int(TWO)); // good...
Matrix<float, Dynamic, TWO> m3(42, TWO); // error!
```

When I compile the declaration of m3 is raising an error as if the enum value `TWO` is a floating point number:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 -c bug.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:366,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from bug.cpp:1:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h: In instantiation of ‘void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_init2(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type::SizeAtCompileTime != 2), T0>::type*) [with T0 = int; T1 = <unnamed enum>; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 2>; Eigen::Index = long int; typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type::SizeAtCompileTime != 2), T0>::type = int]’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:302:35:   required from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T0&, const T1&) [with T0 = int; T1 = <unnamed enum>; _Scalar = float; int _Rows = -1; int _Cols = 2; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = -1; int _MaxCols = 2]’
bug.cpp:6:39:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:740:58: error: static assertion failed: FLOATING_POINT_ARGUMENT_PASSED__INTEGER_WAS_EXPECTED
  740 |       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(bool(NumTraits<T0>::IsInteger) &&
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
  741 |                           bool(NumTraits<T1>::IsInteger),
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:33:54: note: in definition of macro ‘EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT’
   33 |     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
      |
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message is just not chosen well since it always mentions floating points as causing the issue, but the point is that you need to pass an integer type, which an enumeration type is not.

However, with Eigen version 3.3.8 this has been changed and an enumeration type is now accepted as well and will be converted to its underlying integer type, see [this issue](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1692) resulting in [this commit](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/commit/441b3511de7d0a6930dc7643943aa5c6082ab9e1). Since that version your code compiles fine, see https://godbolt.org/z/W4jYbKfns.

Comment: Ok. Is my declaration of `m2` the best workaround in your opinion? I don't want to require a specific version of Eigen since I use it only at a very basic level.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini In general, I would try to avoid the enum and use `constexpr` constants instead, if that makes sense (i.e. if you don't need the specific enumeration type).

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Otherwise, again as a general rule, I would use `std::to_underlying`, or a manual implementation of that since it is C++23 only, so that you don't have a potential type mismatch between the underlying type and `int`.